# How to export a dynamically generated temporary csv file?

Tags: php, file-io, csv, content-type

I would like to generate a csv file with data, that I get by querying a database. The browser then should prompt the user to download the file. By problem is, that the readfile function needs a filename and not a handle, but I can't find a function to get the filename of this temporary file.
I guess there are better ways to do this, but I can't find them.

```
$handle = tmpfile();
fputcsv($handle, array('year', 'month', 'product', 'count'));
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=LS_export');
echo readfile($handle);
fclose($handle);
exit();
```

Comment: you can genereate the file directly from a mysql query

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for [rewind](http://php.net/rewind) to reset the file pointer to the start of the file, followed by [fpassthru](http://php.net/fpassthru) to output all the contents of the file.

```
rewind($handle);
fpassthru($handle);
```

Another solution is to use [tempnam](http://php.net/tempnam) to generate a unique file which is not removed when closed. Do not forget to remove it manually when you are done with it.

```
$name = tempnam('/tmp', 'csv');
$handle = fopen($name, 'w');
...
fclose($handle);
readfile($name);
unlink($name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/", "");
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
...
fclose($handle);
```

And you have the filename too.

Comment: Do not forget to delete the file after. But Emil's solution seems better.

Answer (score 0):

from mysql

```
SELECT id, name, email INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM users WHERE 1
```

and delete it on demand

redefine separators and other param as you need